# Combinatorial proof of $D_n= nD_{n-1}+(-1)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider a finite set $S_n$ with $n\ge 2$ elements and denote by $D_n$ the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $S_n$.

How to prove by a direct combinatorial proof that

$$D_n= nD_{n-1}+(-1)^n ?$$

I know a proof based on Euler equality

$$D_n = (n-1)(D_{n-1} + D_{n-2})$$

and tried to separate the cases $n$ even and odd... but I’m not able to get a clean proof so far.

Comment: Do you mean $D_n= nD_{n-1}+(-1)^n$?

Comment: @RobertZ Yes. Thanks for spotting the typo that I corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I give you a reference to a nice (and short) paper of A. T. Benjamin and J. Ornstein:
[A bijective proof of a derangement recurrence](https://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/55-5/BenjaminOrnstein.pdf). Their bijection is based on the number of elements in the cycle of each permutation which contains the smallest element $1$.

The authors note that Richard Stanley points out in his classic text *Enumerative Combinatorics* that "considerably more work is required to prove such recurrence combinatorially".

Comment: Thanks Robert to point me to those papers. Interesting to see the way to create an *almost* correspondence between the set of derangements and the set of permutations with exactly one fixed point. And how the *almost* covers the term $(-1)^n$ of the equation to be proven.

Comment: I’ll also look at [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669883800341) which is a reference of the article provided in your answer.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Well done! Thanks, I will look through Remmel's article.